# facebook send dialog error 500

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to open a Send dialog. It is working on some ids and fails with error 500 for some.

For example the below links throw error 500.

http://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?to=548207451893117&app_id=&link=http://www.google.com/&redirect_uri=

Same URL works for some ids. For example: id 100003183788238 opens as expected.